# Call objc_collectingEnabled() from objective-c++?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

How would I do this?  At the moment, the compiler complains that 
`"'objc_collectingEnabled()' was not declared in this scope."`  Compiling as with the extension .m fixes this, but then I can't call from another C++ library that I need to use.

Current code:

```
- (void)functionName
{
    if(!objc_collectingEnabled())
    {
        free(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `#include <objc/objc-auto.h>`? That's where the function is declared.